# split elements in a list

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm trying to split the elements in some lists but I can only get each character

example:
split those lists

```
[999.7382621, -1.4637250000000002]
[-1.5490111999999998, 1.5490111999999998]
```

with this code

```
elements = [map(str, line.split(",")) for line in mylists]
```

I get this result:

```
[['9'], ['9'], ['9'], ['.'], ['7'], ['3'], ['8'], ['2'], ['6'], ['2'], ['1'],['', ''], ['-'], ['1'], ['.'], ['4'], ['6'], ['3'], ['7'], ['2'], ['5']]
[['-'], ['1'], ['.'], ['5'], ['4'], ['9'], ['0'], ['1'], ['1'], ['2'], ['', ''], ['1'], ['.'], ['5'], ['4'], ['9'], ['0'], ['1'], ['1'], ['2']]
```

I'd like to get

```
[['999.7382621'],['-1.4637250000000002']]
[['-1.5490111999999998'],['1.5490111999999998']]
```

What did I miss here? Thanks

Comment: Do you want to just cast each element as a string and turn it into a member of a singleton `list`? And the original objects contain no strings, so I don't see how `line.split` works.

Comment: Yes, I'd like to do that.  I got data from a csv file and splitted it, when I put type(data) it says it's a string. I don't know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like `mylists` variable is a single string and when you say

```
elements = [map(str, line.split(",")) for line in mylists]
```

you actually iterating not over lines but over characters. Try:

```
elements = [map(str, line.split(",")) for line in mylists.strip('\n').split('\n')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use something like

```
>>> a = [999.7382621, -1.4637250000000002]
>>> map(lambda x: [str(x)], a)
[['999.7382621'], ['-1.463725']]
>>>
```

Why do you want to use split?

Answer (score 0):

if your original data are lines of a text file:

```
In [135]: line = '[999.7382621, -1.4637250000000002]'

In [136]: import ast

In [137]: ast.literal_eval(line)
Out[137]: [999.7382621, -1.4637250000000002]

In [138]: [[x] for x in ast.literal_eval(line)]
Out[138]: [[999.7382621], [-1.4637250000000002]]
```